# EF 6.1 Scalar-Valued Functions Database First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-function

My application is c# MVC5, using EF 6.1.  Imported tables and functions using Database First.  I can see the function in model (emdx) browser listed under DALModel.Store / Stored Procedures / Functions (grayed out).

I am trying to use the function using the following:

```
using (var ctx = new DALEntities())
{
    int? result = ctx.fn_TotalClient(MemberRepository.AllowedCId, fromDate, toDate);
    return (result != null ? result.Value : 0);
}
```

I get can't resolve fn_TotalClient

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Old issue that still exists in EntityFramework 6.1.2 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/756865e5-ff25-4f5f-aad8-fed9d741c05d/add-scalar-function-to-function-import-folder-in-model-browser-of-entity-framework-40-edmx?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: Glad you got a solution. Would just like to comment that a better way to use the nullable int is to check its `HasValue` property: `return (result.HasValue ? result.Value : 0);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently I could not use Scalar-Valued Function directly into my model; I found a solution in this blog http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/first-impressions-of-database-first-development-with-entity-framework-5-in-visual-studio-2012/.

However, I used a different approach by redeveloping the function as a Table-Valued Function, then used FirstOrDefault() to get the result value.

Hope this could  help someone facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you need to modify SQL to convert the single/scalar value to table valued function then it will work.

> Scalar function as it was, which doesn't work

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha256]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS VARBINARY(32)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT * FROM HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str) AS HASH256 );
END -- this doesn't work.
```

> Scalar function -> Converted to Table Valued function , it works

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSha2561]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS  @returnList TABLE (CODE varbinary(32))
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @returnList
    SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @str);

    RETURN; -- This one works like a charm.

END
```